# How can i parse url from iframe html code?

Tags: javascript, angular, parsing, iframe

I have a vimeo iframe code in db.

`<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/33535353" width="650" height="375" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

How can i get the link from this iframe code.

Expected result: `https://vimeo.com/33535353`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Updated]

This should do the trick

You can try this simple selector. Assuming that the src is at the beginning

```js
let URL = `<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/33535353" width="650" height="375" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>`;
let updatedURLArr = URL.match(/"(.*?)"/)
var updatedURL = updatedURLArr[1].replace('https://player.vimeo.com/video','https://vimeo.com');
console.log(updatedURL)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i have  edited my question. could you please check.
expected result is `https://vimeo.com/33535353`

Comment: If there are multiple, you can iterate through them ofcourse

Comment: I have made changes, you can check now

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
If my iframe code is inside a variable how can i do the first step of your code.
Beacuse i'm taking this from db.

Comment: I've made changes, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Give your iframe an Id. and do this
`document.getElementById("iframeId").src`
and use can use string.replace method to replace "https://player.vimeo.com/video" to "https://vimeo.com/"